Mongo DB fetch on client + NextJS = Maximum call stack size exceeded
I have a component where I get answers to a post, and I want the answers to be displayed like an infinite scroll, but when I call the Server Action on the client, I get the error Maximum call stack size exceeded.
The server actions:
export async function getAnswers(params: GetAnswersParams) {
  try {
    connectToDatabase();

    const { questionId, sortBy, page = 1, pageSize = 10 } = params;

    const skipAmount = (page - 1) * pageSize;

    let sortOptions = {};

    switch (sortBy) {
      case 'highestUpvotes':
        sortOptions = { upvotes: -1 };
        break;
      case 'lowestUpvotes':
        sortOptions = { upvotes: 1 };
        break;
      case 'recent':
        sortOptions = { createdAt: -1 };
        break;
      case 'old':
        sortOptions = { createdAt: 1 };
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    const answers = await Answer.find({ question: questionId })
      .populate('author', '_id clerkId name picture')
      .sort(sortOptions)
      .skip(skipAmount)
      .limit(pageSize);

    const totalAnswers = await Answer.countDocuments({
      question: questionId,
    });

    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalAnswers / pageSize);

    const isNext = totalAnswers > skipAmount + answers.length;

    return { answers, isNext, totalPages };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}

The server component:
const AllAnswers = async ({ questionId, userId, totalAnswers, page, filter }: Props) => {
  const { answers, isNext, totalPages } = await getAnswers({
    questionId,
    page: page ? +page : 1,
    sortBy: filter,
  });

  return (
    <div className='mt-11'>
      <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
        <h3 className='primary-text-gradient'>{`${totalAnswers} ${totalAnswers === 1 ? 'Answer' : 'Answers'}`}</h3>

        <Filter filters={AnswerFilters} />
      </div>

      <LoadMoreAnswers
        initialAnswers={JSON.stringify(answers)}
        questionId={JSON.stringify(questionId)}
        userId={userId}
        filter={filter}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllAnswers;

The client component:
const LoadMoreAnswers = ({ initialAnswers, questionId, userId, filter }: Props) => {
  const [allAnswers, setAllAnswers] = useState(JSON.parse(initialAnswers));
  // const { ref, inView } = useInView();

  const loadMoreAnswers = async () => {
    try {
      const newAnswers = await getAnswers({
        questionId: JSON.parse(questionId),
        page: 2,
        sortBy: 'recent',
      });

      // setAllAnswers((oldAnswers) => [...oldAnswers, ...newAnswers]);

      console.log(newAnswers);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading more answers:', error);
    }
  };



  return (
    <>
      {allAnswers.map((answer) => (
        <article key={answer._id} className='light-border border-b py-10'>
          <div className='mb-8 flex flex-col-reverse justify-between gap-5 sm:flex-row sm:items-center sm:gap-2'>
            <Link
              href={`/profile/${answer.author.clerkId}`}
              className='flex flex-1 items-start gap-1 sm:items-center'
            >
              <Image
                src={answer.author.picture}
                alt='profile picture'
                width={18}
                height={18}
                className='rounded-full object-cover max-sm:mt-0.5'
              />
              <div className='flex flex-col sm:flex-row sm:items-center'>
                <p className='body-semibold text-dark300_light700'>
                  {answer.author.name}
                </p>
                <p className='small-regular text-dark400_light500 mt-0.5 line-clamp-1'>
                  <span className='mx-0.5 max-sm:hidden'>•</span>
                  {/* answered {getTimestamp(answer.createdAt)} */}
                </p>
              </div>
            </Link>

            <div className='flex justify-end'>
              <Votes
                type='Answer'
                itemId={JSON.stringify(answer._id)}
                userId={userId}
                upvotes={answer.upvotes.length}
                hasupVoted={answer.upvotes.includes(userId)}
                downvotes={answer.downvotes.length}
                hasdownVoted={answer.downvotes.includes(userId)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <ParseHTML data={answer.content} />
        </article>
      ))}

      {/* <div className='mt-11 flex w-full items-center justify-center' ref={ref}> */}
      {/* <Icons.Spinner className='size-10 animate-spin' /> */}
      <Button onClick={loadMoreAnswers}>Load more</Button>
      {/* </div> */}
    </>
  );
};

export default LoadMoreAnswers;

I tried to do it with a spinner at the bottom, using react-intersection-observer, but now I just added a button to test the fetch and it doesn't work... I don't understand why it doesn't work.
For now, I just want to add page 2 when clicking the button, then I think I can figure out the rest.

First remark i see in your code is that you call a server action in a client component but the action isn't declared as server action. Also if you have to await for a server action response in a client component, one way is to use useTransition hook.
Step 1: Make use you server action file starts with 'use server'
Step 2: in your client component, add this:
const [isLoading, startTransition] = useTransition();
const [allAnswers, setAllAnswers] = useState(JSON.parse(initialAnswers));
  // const { ref, inView } = useInView();

  const loadMoreAnswers = () => startTransition(async () => {
    try {
      const newAnswers = await getAnswers({
        questionId: JSON.parse(questionId),
        page: 2,
        sortBy: 'recent',
      });

      // setAllAnswers((oldAnswers) => [...oldAnswers, ...newAnswers]);

      console.log(newAnswers);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading more answers:', error);
    }
  });

You can use the isLoading state to show a loading spinner or whatever.

have multiple server actions in that file. "use server" is declared at the top of the file. I still get that error when clicking Load more. Thanks though.

did you check if you don't have any recursive call inside your client components?

This is the correct server action up to this point. Notice the total pages implementation might've been wrong too. The problem was the format I was returning the answers from the server action:
    export async function getAnswers(params: GetAnswersParams) {
  try {
    connectToDatabase();

    const { questionId, sortBy, page = 1, pageSize = 5 } = params;

    const skipAmount = (page - 1) * pageSize;

    let sortOptions = {};
    switch (sortBy) {
      case 'highestUpvotes':
        sortOptions = { upvotes: -1 };
        break;
      case 'lowestUpvotes':
        sortOptions = { upvotes: 1 };
        break;
      case 'recent':
        sortOptions = { createdAt: -1 };
        break;
      case 'old':
        sortOptions = { createdAt: 1 };
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    const answers = await Answer.find({ question: questionId })
      .populate('author', '_id clerkId name picture')
      .sort(sortOptions)
      .skip(skipAmount)
      .limit(pageSize);

    const totalAnswers = await Answer.countDocuments({
      question: questionId,
    });

    // const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalAnswers / pageSize);

    const isNext = totalAnswers > skipAmount + answers.length;

    return {
      answers: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(answers)),
      isNext,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}

